# Understanding the cd_dynamic_conf file

Tags: 2011, content-delivery

Is there any documentation on how to use the cd_dynamic_conf.xml?

There's the [online reference](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/pub.xql?action=home&pub=SDL_Tridion_2011_SPONE&lang=en-US#docid=reference_51F0101F6A114F318267FE7F1B5133FD&addHistory=true&query=&scope=&tid=&filename=CDConfigRef_DCD.xml&resource=&inner_id=&eventType=lcContent.loadDocreference_51F0101F6A114F318267FE7F1B5133FD&url=/LiveContent/web/search.xql?c=t&pub=SDL_Tridion_2011_SPONE&lang=en-US&action=search&query=URLMappings&sid=lcSearch.runSearch1403089531847&currentQuery=URLMappings&currentScope=), but nothing describing usage and why you might need/want to use it.

StaticMappings nodes appear to be straight forward enough - dynamic links can be generated as absolute URLs not relative ones using the Host node information.

The StorageMapping node is a little less clear - is the IdentifyPublicationByProperty an enumeration, what other value can it be and why would you change it?

Answer (score 3):

As i understand it, the cd_dynamic_conf is only revelant if you wish to use REL in XPM sites. Normally XPM can figure this out by looking at the tags in the page, but session preview through REL can't access this and therefor looks at this configuration file. I always keep it in the default state since i don't use REL ...

Comment: Interesting Rogier - I didn't know the file was only in use for REL.

Answer (score 2):

This section of `cd_dynamic_conf.xml` is very important for XPM & Session Preview to work correctly.

```
<URLMappings>
        <StaticMappings>
            <!-- The Publications element is a container for separate Publication elements. -->
            <Publications>
                <!-- The publication element allows you to specify Publication specific settings.
                 The Id indicates the id of the publication. This should be a number. -->
                <Publication Id="xx">
                    <!-- The Host element allows you to specify information about the site that
                        can be used to create URLs for Dynamic Links.
                        The following attributes are specified:
                           Domain    The domain of the website, for example www.tridion.com.
                           Port      The port of the website, for instance 8080.
                           Path      The path of the virtual directory of your website.
                           Protocol  The protocol used for the website. -->
                    <Host Domain="xyz.building-blocks.com" Port="80" Protocol="http" Path=""/>
                </Publication>
            </Publications>
        </StaticMappings>
        <StorageMapping IdentifyPublicationByProperty="publicationUrl"/>
    </URLMappings>
```

If this is incorrectly configured you will see symptoms like:

- Not redirecting to page correctly when creating new page via XPM
- Temporary Session Preview files not being created correctly